# WPF scrolling parent container through child container

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollview

I'm having some issues trying to figure out how to scroll the content of a grid which is contained inside of a scroll viewer. When trying to scroll with the mouse wheel or pan (with a touch screen), the grid scrolls fine if the mouse/touch point is over an empty area, but if it is above certain controls (ex. a group box) it won't scroll. Is there some property I'm missing to allow the child panels to allow them to scroll their parent containers?

**EDIT:**
I incorrectly stated my original layout. Here's a simplified version of my senario:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox />    <--Doesn't Scroll-->
            <Button />     <--Scrolls Fine-->
            <TextBlock />  <--Scrolls Fine-->
            <TextBox />    <--Scrolls Fine-->
            <DataGrid />   <--Doesn't Scroll-->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

A coworker pointed out that my issue is due to the fact the controls such as a ListBoxes and DataGrids contain ScrollViewers themselves, this makes sense. His suggestion (which would work but we both agree seems more complex than it should be) is to catch and rethrow the the scroll event in the code behind (and likely have to deal with calculating the smount of offset to scroll) so that it can bubble up to "MainScrollViewer".

**EDIT 2:**
It seems like the only way to achieve this is to use code behind to handle the PreviewMouseWheel event in the parent. That works, but how do I go about implementing the same thing for panning (scrolling by finger on a touch screen)?

Comment: You do know that the grid contains a `ScrollViewer` in it?  There's no need to put it in a `ScrollViewer` . . .  If you have VS2013 installed, you can find the templates that are used for every control that ships with VS in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\SystemThemes\Wpf

Comment: When you say 'grid', are you referring to a `Grid` panel, or a data grid control?

Comment: Also, if the `Background` of a control is `Transparent`, hit testing fails.  Change the `Background` to some other color & test.

Comment: @TonyVitabile I believe you're thinking of a null `Background`.  A `Transparent` background should hit test just fine.  The only exception is when you are in a layered window with a zero-alpha background, in which case WPF won't receive the input events.

Comment: @MikeStrobel You're correct. That is what I was thinking of.

Comment: I edited my question with more clarification. Also I can't use the null background method as it wouldn't fit my UI aesthetically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ScrollViewer's PreviewMouseWheel event and ScrollToVerticalOffset method...

```
private void ScrollViewerOnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var scv = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (scv == null) return;
    scv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scv.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is more or less what my coworker and I had discussed. If there is no other way, then I shall use this method, but it seems as if there should be an easier way, on that preferably doesn't involve code behind...in my above example the StackPanel and it's contents are actually a separate user control, so I'd have to insert this code behind to all of it's calling parents, it seems likely that down the road someone will forget to do this and run into the same issues I'm currently having.

Answer (score 11):

Create a bubbling scrollbehavior for your scrollview:

```c#
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

public sealed class BubbleScrollEvent : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            var e2 = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta) { RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent };
            AssociatedObject.RaiseEvent(e2);
        }
    }
}
```

Add this behavior to your scrollviewer:

```c#
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ViewAddons:BubbleScrollEvent />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: This is definitely a more cleaner approach than the one marked answer . More reusable .

Comment: Attaching this behavior to the outside ScrollViewer works just as expected. This should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: For me, it started working when I attached it to the child ListBox, not the parent. I don't know why, perhaps I have a different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For Starters, be sure you are using the Tech that already exists. That may resolve your issue.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Although if that doesn't resolve the issue, and i know this sounds strange, Set the background color of the grid AND problem object to #00000000. (if it is not already assigned a color/brush)

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Background="#00000000"/>
```

I know its strange, but when I have these problems it works every time. I have no idea why it works. Something to do with transparency.